# Get all 'where' calls using ExpressionVisitor

Tags: c#, linq, expression-trees, iqueryable, lambda

I have a query, like such:

```
var query = from sessions in dataSet
                    where (names.Contains(sessions.Username))
                    where (sessions.Login.TimeOfAction == dt)                    
                    select new {    sessions.Username, 
                                    sessions.Login, 
                                    sessions.Logout, sessions.Duration };
```

I want to implement an ExpressionVisitor to extract BOTH the where clauses as Lambda's, but so far have only been able to get the first using a class called 'InnermostWhereFinder' that comes from the MSDN tutorial on a custom query provider for the TerraServer web-service.

It is:

```
internal class InnermostWhereFinder : ExpressionVisitor
    {
        private MethodCallExpression innermostWhereExpression;

        public MethodCallExpression GetInnermostWhere(Expression expression)
        {
            Visit(expression); 
            return innermostWhereExpression;
        }

        protected override Expression VisitMethodCall(MethodCallExpression expression)
        {
            if (expression.Method.Name == "Where")
                innermostWhereExpression = expression;

            Visit(expression.Arguments[0]);

            return expression;
        }
    }
```

Ive tried tweaking this class heavily to return both where clauses with no success. Couldn't find any great documentation on this, can anyone help? This will ultimately need to result in multiple LambdaExpression objects I can work with, I think.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the class found here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb882521%28v=vs.90%29.aspx as your base. You can then create your Visitor like this

```
internal class WhereFinder : ExpressionVisitor
    {
        private IList<MethodCallExpression> whereExpressions = new List<MethodCallExpression>();

        public IList<MethodCallExpression> GetWhere(Expression expression)
        {
            Visit(expression); 
            return whereExpressions;
        }

        protected override Expression VisitMethodCall(MethodCallExpression expression)
        {
            if (expression.Method.Name == "Where")
                whereExpressions.Add(expression);

            Visit(expression.Arguments[0]);

            return expression;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, that works. One additional question...do you know if its possible to also remove certain where clauses from the Exp tree?

Comment: In your VisitMethodCall where you are adding the expression to the list. You can do some kind of test and then instead of returning the expression you can replace the second argument with a constant condition. Something like 1 == 1