# Detect where applied to IQueryable<T>

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

How can I detect if a `IQueryable<T>` has a `where` filter applied?

In this code, I need to know programmatically that `queryFiltered` has a `where` applied to it and `query` doesn't

```
IQueryable<Customer> query = Context.Customers;
IQueryable<Customer> queryFiltered = Context.Customers
                                            .Where(c=>c.Name.Contains("ABC"));
```

Comment: Why? giving more context might help give a better answer

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You will have to parse the [`Expression`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.expressions.expression.aspx) that is returned from the [`Expression` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.iqueryable.expression.aspx) on the [`IQueryable<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb351562.aspx) implementation.

You'll have to query for the [`Queryable.Where` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.queryable.where.aspx) being called as you crawl the `Expression` tree.

Also note that while `Queryable.Where` is going to be the most common way to detect a `where` filter, query syntax allows for other implementations to be used (depending on what namespaces are used in the [`using` directives](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf0df423.aspx)); if you have something that is not using the `Queryable.Where` extension method then you'll have to look for that explicitly (or use a more generic method of filtering for a `Where` method that takes an `IQueryable<T>` and returns an `IQueryable<T>`).

The [`ExpressionVisitor` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.expressions.expressionvisitor.aspx) (as [pointed out by xanatos](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7902721/detect-where-applied-to-iqueryablet/7902840#7902840)) provides a very easy way of crawling the `Expression` tree, I highly recommend using that approach as a base for processing your `Expression` tree.

Of note is that `ExpressionVisitor` class implementations are required to store and expose state on the class level.  Because of that, it would be best (IMO) to create internal classes that perform the action one-time and then have a public method which creates a new instance of the `ExpressionVisitor` every time; this will help with dealing with mutating state, and if done properly, will allow the method to be thread-safe as well (if that is a concern of yours).

Answer (score 5):

If you are using C# 4.0 you can use this sample code: [Get all 'where' calls using ExpressionVisitor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4515550/get-all-where-calls-using-expressionvisitor/4515615#4515615)

It's based on `ExpressionVisitor`. It "visits" the various elements of a `IQueryable<T>` to find the `Where` parts. It seems simple enough.

If you are on C# = 3.5, you can use the `ExpressionVisitor` sample from MSDN's [How to: Implement an Expression Tree Visitor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb882521(v=vs.90).aspx) PLUS the `WhereFinder` from the previous link (they work correctly together, just tested)

To use the code:

```
var wf = new WhereFinder();
var wheres = wf.GetWhere(query.Expression);

if (wheres.Any())
{
    // There are Where in the query!
}
```

If you are (correctly) as much paranoid as `Rune FS`, to the `WereFinder.VisitMethodCall`, change the `if` to

```
if (expression.Method.Name == "Where" && expression.Method.DeclaringType.FullName == "System.Linq.Queryable")
```

Comment: all it basically does is search for a method called "where" which would easily be fooled by another non filtering method that's called where

Comment: @RuneFS Corrected. But I DO think you should post the correction to the original Q/A :-)

Comment: The original post relates to a specific scenario where the expression tree is known upfront an OP wants to extract the two where clauses as expressions.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way is call `q.Expression.ToString().Contains(".Where(")`. As you can see, `query.Expression.ToString().Contains(".Where(")` returns false while `queryFiltered.Expression.ToString().Contains(".Where(")` returns true.

You may need more complexity than that if you count other expressions as "filtering", but that is true with the expression visitor approach too.

There's something rather hacky about this I'll grant you, but it does seem much simpler.

Comment: `new int[] { }.AsQueryable().Select(p => ".Where(").ToString().Contains(".Where(")` :-)

Comment: @xanatos Now that's just perverse! :)

Comment: @xanatos the same can be done for the ExpressionVisitor approach overload Where so that it works exactly as select and it would seem you were filtering where indeed you'd be projecting

Comment: @RuneFS Yes, clearly. You could filter the Where a little better by using its fullname (so Queryable.Where`number)

Comment: You could go better still with the ExpressionVisitor approach and match on types IIRC, so it can be made bullet-proof where this can't. It should also be faster with really complex expressions. I did say mine was hacky, didn't I :) It's offered only for comparison, since ExpressionVisitor approach was already given in an answer.

Comment: Short of analyzing the method body of every method called you can't make it bullet proof if you wish to find all filters. A select method can filter, a where can project and so it goes for them all. There's no restriction on what they actually do

Comment: Yep. We're stuck with having to either go into **immense** detail, or decide a level is "good enough". The answer I give is cruder than those already given, but would hit "good enough" for some cases, hence by throwing it into the mix :)